# Mocking a Using with a FileStream

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have been trying to mock out a using with a file stream but have not been able to complete this and am unsure how to do it, I am using rhino mock.

```
private Connection LoadConnectionDetailsFromDisk(string bodyFile)
{     
   //logic before
   using (FileStream fs = File.Open(bodyFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
   {
     return this.serverConfiguration.LoadConfiguration(fs, flowProcess);
   }
    //more logic
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to mock the using(FileStream....) so I am able to access this branch of the code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to abstract `File.Open()` by an interface method then you would be able mocking call to it.

So

1) Create an interface:

```
public interface IFileDataSource
{
   FileStream Open(string path,
                   FileMode mode,
                   FileAccess access,
                   FileShare share);
}
```

2) Change `LoadConnectionDetailsFromDisk()` as following:

```
private Connection LoadConnectionDetailsFromDisk(string path, IFileDataSource fileSource)
{     
   using (FileStream fs = fileSource.Open(bodyFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
   {
      return this.serverConfiguration.LoadConfiguration(fs, flowProcess);
   }

   //more logic
}
```

3) In a test mock the interface and inject a mock

```
// create a mock instance
var sourceMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFileDataSource>();

// setup expectation
sourceMock.Expect(m => m.Open("path", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
         .CallBack(
 delegate (string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
 {
      // handle a call

     return true;
 }).Repeat.Any();

// TODO: depends on how you are triggering LoadConnectionDetailsFromDisk method call
// inject a mock
```

Considering that `LoadConnectionDetailsFromDisk()` you can not inject mock directly to this method call froma  test so please show how this method is invoked.

Comment: How should I call `LoadConnectionDetailsFromDisk` in normal code (outside of tests) ?

Answer (score 4):

The [System.IO.Abstractions project](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions) and [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Abstractions/) also allow for mocking of `FileStreams`.

To use that you have to slightly change how you get the FileStream in the first place, to something like:

```
private readonly IFileSystem _fileSystem; // this is from the third-party System.IO.Abstractions package

// This is assuming dependency injection to insert the mock file system during testing, 
// or the real one in production
public YourConstructor(IFileSystem fileSystem)
{
   _fileSystem = fileSystem;
}

private Connection LoadConnectionDetailsFromDisk(string bodyFile)
{     
   using (Stream fs = _fileSystem.FileStream.Create(bodyFile, FileMode.Open))
   {
       return this.serverConfiguration.LoadConfiguration(fs, flowProcess);
   }

   //more logic
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the below code snippet for mocking FileStream

```
Mock<FileStream> mockFileStream = new Mock<FileStream>(new IntPtr(1), FileAccess.Read);
```

In this way, you create a new instance of FileStream, and you can use it like below

```
mockObject.Setup(s => s.GetFileStream(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockFileStream.Object);
```

mockObject is any og your Interface to return FileStream

Comment: This used to be a nice solution, but unfortunately fails with .NET 6.0, as some additional verifications for valid handles have been added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SystemWrapper](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FileInfo%20Tutorial&referringTitle=Home) lib for this purpose. It contains interfaces and classes wrapping system classes and enables you to unit tests methods using this classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the method so that the FileStream is passed to the method so that you can create a mock of the filestream

```
private Connection LoadConnectionDetailsFromDisk(FileStream bodyFile)
{ 
  ....
}
```

if you really want to get fancy you can always accept a IStream and then Mock that IStream but Rhino support creating mocks of concreate classes

```
 MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
 FileStream basket = mocks.CreateMock<FileStream>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled it by creating a `FileStream` subclass. The base constructor *does* require that we open an actual file, so I include a simple text file set to "Content" and "Include if newer", which we open read-only and sharable.

Then I overwrite the method that I actually need. In my case, I need the write method, and I need to do something with what is written, so I inject a callback to invoke.

```
private class CustomFileStream : FileStream
{
    private Action<string> WriteAction { get; }
    public CustomFileStream(Action<string> writeAction)
        // FileStream is notoriously hard to mock, so we inherit from it and we are a lightweight, real (but unused) FileStream underneath
        : base(Path.Combine(new ExecutionDirectory().Path /* Handle the execution directory in your own way */, "Content/DummyTextFile.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    {
        this.WriteAction = writeAction;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => true;
    public override void Write(ReadOnlySpan<byte> buffer)
    {
        this.WriteAction(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
    }
}
```